# Generate .ics from json

Tags: jquery, .net, json, outlook, icalendar

I'm trying to export a calendar to Outlook from a JSON data stream.
I'm pretty sure I could do this sort of thing in .NET by rendering the response with the following header definitions:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=CalendarEvent1.ics");
```

I'm using the following jQuery to retrieve the data and I've verified that the data is coming back properly, but I'm stuck on how to proceed with rendering the output such that it will open as a calendar in Outlook.  I'm sure it's something I'd need to add to the success: function(data){} block, but I'm not sure exactly what.  I think I can figure out how to iterate through the JSON elements and pull the necessary data (title, start, end, etc.), but I don't know where/how to set the header information and how to ensure the stream is output in a new window I guess (so the existing screen isn't affected)?  I basically just want the user to click on the "Export Calendar" link and a new calendar will open in Outlook with the event dates from the JSON response.  Thanks.

```
$('#ExportCal').click(function() {
    var jData = {officeId:"0", filter:"All", start:"2016-01-31", end:"2016-03-13"};

    $.ajax({
        url: "@(Url.Content("~/Solicitation/GetEventDates/"))",
        type: 'GET',
        data: jData,
        success: function(data) {                
        }                    
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't do it with jQuery or ajax. Make it a direct link.

Comment: Ok... made it a direct link to http://xxxxx/Solicitation/GetEventDates/?officeId=0&filter=All&start=2016-01-31&end=2016-03-13  which makes the JSON render to the browser (which is progress I think), but how do I manipulate that output such that the header includes ("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=CalendarEvent1.ics")?

Comment: You must do that server-side. It's not something you can control in the client.

Comment: Oh ok, so I'll have to modify the method that is called by the route to "Solicitation/GetEventDates" to return a text stream containing the header information as well as the JSON data.  I will see if I can get that to work.  Thanks for the guidance.